# Unable to pass parameters when using pyodbc in Django for large query

Tags: python, django, t-sql, pyodbc, azure-synapse

Working on:
Django framework
pyodbc package (MSSQL Version 18)
DS: Azure synapse

I would like to know what is the best way to go about when trying to load a large number of parameters into the SQL query for Azure synapse.

The scale I'm looking for is in millions.

I can split the parameters into chunks of 2k which is the limit specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits#queries

However, that would mean the number of queries would be too many. ~500 per million parameters.

This isn't just for 1 type of parameter for e.g in where clause I may have 2 columns, each column with its own set of a million values which I would like to pass through the query params.

What's the best way to about this?

As a sidenote: I hadn't been able to get the queries working with '?' parameter holder, I had to use '%s' to fix this.

Thanking in advance!

Comment: If you need *millions* of parameters something has gone very wrong. Perhaps you need a table type parameter? Perhaps something else is the problem entirely. Either way, this is almost certainly an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Agree with Thom A in that it would be better if to rethink and refactor your problem so that you don't have to do this. Short of that, you could format your data as XML, JSON, or (possibly the simplest) a single string containing a list of value pairs - possibly formatted like `"A1,A2|B1,B2|..."`, with care not to use delimiters that might also be in your data. That string would then be passed as a single parameter that could be parsed and loaded into a temporary table (and possibly indexed) on the server side. (Using dynamic SQL or separate parameters is likely just overloading the parser.)

Comment: I need to pass a list of strings in the 'IN' operator. I'm under the assumption that we'll need to each value as a different parameter. Is it not the case?
Edit: This list has values in scale of millions.

Comment: SQL Server's limit for parameters to a stored procedure or user-defined function is 2,100, and I wouldn't be surprised if that same limit applies here.

Comment: @FlipperPA Yes, that's pretty much it. 2098 is the limit. How do we get around it for large number of parameters? Any workarounds?

Comment: I used to be very active with pyodbc and helped maintain the SQL Server engine for Django, but am now fully on PostgreSQL. My organization migrated over five years, and have been very happy. That was our “workaround”  I understand not everyone is in a position to affect that kind of organizational change. Sorry I can’t be more help!

Comment: @FlipperPA Haha.. good for you :). Not in a position to migrate atm! I'm now exploring uploading the list to Blob Storage and then trying to use it the query somehow. Hopefully, this be it. Anyway, have a great year ahead!